# What connection string do I use for Classic ASP and Oracle 10g?

Tags: asp-classic, oracle10g, dsn

I have Oracle 10g and have installed ODBC via the instant client.  I am able to use the ODBC administrator and set up a DSN and test successfully, and whenever I use Microsoft Access I can connect to my database no problem.  I can also use Visual Web Developer to traverse the data.

But, when I try and use Classic ASP with:

myConn.Open "DSN=oracle10g;" & _ 
"Uid=myOracleUsername;" & "Pwd=myOraclePassword"

I get:

-2147467259Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 5 (Oracle in instantclient10_2).
An error occurred while trying to create Server Object.

I have searched various places but nothing seems to work.  All ORACLE_HOME, TNSnames, IUSR_X security, all is correct.  I am thinking it is a DSN connection string problem.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following DSN-less connection string:

```
myConn.Open "Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=instance_name;User ID=myOracleUsername;Password=myOraclePassword"
```

I've used this exact connection string for older version of Oracle client, but can't see any reason why it won't work for your version as well.

Comment: thanks for your help.  it work but I don't know that it's using ODBC.  I had to put my tnsnames entry not my odbc entry.

Comment: Cheers @johnny - what you mean by "tnsnames entry" though?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle